# POST data behaving strangely after jquery mobile form submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms

When I submit my form and use PHP's var_dump on $date it shows the correct variable value in my web browser but it will NOT write the value into the source code and instead shows NULL. Here's my code.

```
<form name="newItemForm" id="newItemForm" method="POST" action="record3.php" data-ajax="false">
<input type="hidden" name="storeID" value="<?=$storeID;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?=$date;?>" />

<p><label for="itemname">Item name</label>
<input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname" autofocus /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" /></p>
<p><a href="home.php">Cancel</a></p>
```

When the form submits it goes to record3.php where I have this:

```
if(isset($_POST['storeID'])) { $storeID = $_POST['storeID']; }
if(isset($_POST['date'])) { $date = $_POST['date']; }
?>
<h3>Transaction</h3>
<form name="transactionForm" id="transactionForm" method="POST" action="record2.php" data-ajax="false">
<input type="hidden" name="storeID" value="<?=$storeID;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?=$date;?>" />
<?php
var_dump($date);
die(); ?>
```

When I check my source code in the web browser I see this:

```
<form name="transactionForm" id="transactionForm" method="POST" action="record2.php" data-ajax="false">
<input type="hidden" name="storeID" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="" />
NULL
```

I can't post a picture but this is copied from what I see on the webpage itself where the NULL is showing up in the source code of that same webpage: string(8) "12222013". How could I see one thing in the webpage and another thing when I view that webpage's source code (as viewed from the web browser)?

Comment: You will never see PHP in the code source in your browser.

Comment: The code you are looking at is first time visit on page or after you post back. Your $_POST is only filled with data when your post back to the page and if you are just visiting the url first time your $_POST is not isset and you should set date to something so it appears in date field by default.

Comment: The HTML for the form is actually in record2.php (the first piece of code above). The second piece of code is from record3.php (where the form's action sends the data) so the $_POST should be filled. In fact, given that the web browser shows string(8) "12222013" when $date is dumped it seems like it IS filled. But strangely it won't echo $date's value (or $_POST['date'] for that matter) and when I look at the page's source code the var_dump doesn't show string(8) "12222013" but NULL.